# Graph API call from SPFX tab with MS Graph Client

Tags: spfx-webparts, microsoft-graph, graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, ms-graph-client

**Can we call Graph API directly through MS Graph Client for SPFX tab in team Desktop??**

Here is the sample of git which call Graph API directly in teams tab without any authentication flow or access token with only using Ms Graph Client
[Spfx tab with Graph API](https://github.com/pnp/teams-dev-samples/tree/main/samples/tab-aad-spfx)

Answer (score 1):

In SPFx web part you will  require to request permissions as below.

```
"webApiPermissionRequests": [
      {
        "resource": "Microsoft Graph",
        "scope": "Sites.ReadWrite.All"
      }
    
]
```

Once admin approve it you can call API using MSGraphClient.

Call graph api using MSGraphClient refer the below code.

```
export default class HelloWorldWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IHelloWorldWebPartProps> {
  public render(): void {
    // ...

    this.context.msGraphClientFactory
      .getClient()
      .then((client: MSGraphClient): void => {
        // use MSGraphClient here
      });
  }

  // ...
}
```

- [Use the MSGraphClient to connect to Microsoft Graph](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-msgraph)
- For add the tab in team app refer this docs.
- [Build Microsoft Team tab using SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/using-web-part-as-ms-teams-tab)

Comment: Thanks, I am able to achieve Graph API call in SPFX webpart and able to add that in Teams Tab but my question is that MS Graph Client is not working in Spfx team tab in Microsoft team DESKTOP